# Skipping header rows - is it possible with Cloud DataFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've created a Pipeline, which reads from a file in GCS, transforms it, and finally writes to a BQ table. The file contains a header row (fields).

Is there any way to programatically set the "number of header rows to skip" like you can do in BQ when loading in?

[image: number of header rows to skip]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  It sounds like there are two potential requests here:

- Specifying presence and skip behavior for header lines for a BigQuery import.
- Specifying that a GCS text source should skip a header line.

Future work on this is tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-123.

Also, in the meantime, you could add a simple filter to your ParDo code to skip headers.  Something like this:

```
PCollection<X> rows = ...;
PCollection<X> nonHeaders =
   rows.apply(Filter.by(new MatchIfNonHeader()));
```

Comment: Is there some kind of filter component that I can apply? Or do you just mean skipping the header in the actual "processElement" method of my ParDo code by checking if it's the header?

Comment: one way could be start processing in PerDO and check if that line contains header because if does than skip it

Comment: was this ever addressed as a feature?

Comment: Is this some kind of Joke from Apache Beam ? This is such a trivial feature but still not available in 2024.