# How to export an csv file to a bigqery table using java dataflow?

Tags: export-to-csv, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to read an csv file from the cloud bucket and write it to a bigquery table with columns using dataflow in java. How can I set the headers to the csv file while writing to bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues to solve here

1. Skipping the header when reading the data, and
2. Using the header to correctly populate teh bigquery table columns.

For (1) this is, as of June 2019, [not implemented natively](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-123), though you could try the options listed at [Skipping header rows - is it possible with Cloud DataFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450554/skipping-header-rows-is-it-possible-with-cloud-dataflow). For (2) the easiest would be to read the first line of your CSV in your main program, and pass the list of column names in the constructor to a DoFn that converts CSV lines into TableRow objects ready to write to Bigquery.

Your final program would look something like

```java
public void CsvToBigquery(csvInputPattern, bigqueryTable) {
  final String[] columns = readAndSplitFirstLineOfFirstFile(csvInputPattern);
  Pipeline p = new Pipeline.create(...);
  p
    .apply(TextIO.read().from(csvInputPattern)
    .apply(Filter.by(new MatchIfNonHeader())
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TableRow>() {
             ... // use columns here to TableRows
           })
    .apply(BigtableIO.write().withTableId(bigqueryTable)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar task and used Apache Common library in ParDo function to extract the data from CSV files and then converted them to Table Row Objects for BQ.

```
String fileData = c.element();
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8"));
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader,CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords(); 

for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    checkAndConvertIntoBqDataType(csvRecord.toMap());
    c.output(row);
}
```